# Connect a salesforce user to another salesforce user in another org without any user intervention

Tags: salesforce, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0

We would like to connect a salesforce user to another salesforce user in another org without any user intervention from a service.

We have tried SAML Bearer Flow (using Remote Access Application) to connect to salesforce to retreive Access Token for one of our product. We are referring to the follwoing article.

http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_SAML_bearer_flow.htm

As referred by the SF article for this flow, it uses a previous user authorization to connect and retreive Token. In case the user (for whom Token is requested) has not already authorized the App, SF takes you to the Authorization page first and app will get the access token once app is authorized. This is working fine too. However it has this painful step of users authorizing the app before we can use this flow for the product. It would be good and simplified if this step can be done once for an org and the article does mentions that either User or Admin can authorize the app. However I am not able to find how an Admin can authorize the remote access application.

Does anyone knows and can guide how can an Admin authorize an App or is thre any other way we can achieve our requirement. Any thoughts will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth1 and OAuth2 require user intervention by design.  Anything you do to defeat this would be circumspect and not best practice.  You could make it easy on the user, but you will always have the initial "Authorize this app" message.

If you are trying to make it easy for the user to login to either org, then you may want to consider a hub-and-spoke SSO solution.  [See this doc.](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Implementing_Single_Sign-On_Across_Multiple_Organizations)

If you are trying to pass information between two Salesforce instances, then you may want to consider Salesforce2Salesforce, or outbound workflow.  However, this is done at system context, not user context.

If you want to maintain user context and security, you should consider the new Salesforce Canvas API.  Canvas allows you to call an outbound service, and pass credentials to the service so that it can communicate back.  There is no reason the foreign service could not be a Salesforce instance.